# Copy first and second rows from table to another?

Tags: c#, sql, copy, field, rows

How can I copy from first and second rows only specific fields from one table to another table in C#?

```
insert into table1 select colum1, column2,... from table2
```

Comment: The solutions below nonwithstanding it should be noted, that unless you read the rows ordered by something, there is no order in an SQL table's rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 insert into Table1 (Column1,Column2,..) select Top 2 Column1,Column2 From Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's SQL, you can use the [TOP statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) on your source query

Answer (score 0):

you have answered the question to an extent already

```
insert into table1 select colum1, column2,... from table2
```

you can use static values if you wish in the select statement, or change the column names

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

use the top statement, to pick top 2 rows, or if its mysql use the limit keyword to fetch top 2 rows.